# Is ReadyBoost necessary when Windows 7 has enough memory?

Tags: readyboost, memory-management, memory-limit

[According to Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/readyboost)

> ReadyBoost is designed to help when your PC's memory is running low. Low memory can make your computer sluggish because Windows, which needs a place to stash data, turns to the hard drive. Flash memory offers a speedier alternative.

In my 64-bit system I have 4GB of memory and for my uses, even with heavy multitasking, I don't reach this limit. Is there a good reason to still use a spare USB and activate **ReadyBoost** or will it only be a silly dongle sticking out of my notebook?

Answer (score 4):

If you never come close to running low on memory there is no need for ReadyBoost. The most appropriate situation in which it comes in handy is when a notebook cannot physically support more memory modules but more RAM is required.

Answer (score 3):

USB 2.0 transfer speed is slow and the read/write speed of your average USB flash drive is even slower than that, so the performance rather questionable.

ReadyBoost is no substitute for physical memory (which is still cheap enough).

ReadyBoost is just an option if you're really, really strapped for memory in the middle of nowhere. :)

And here's an extensive analysis you may find interesting:

**[Ready Boost is no match for RAM](http://www.tgdaily.com/hardware-features/30878-analysis-vistas-ready-boost-is-no-match-for-ram)**